# Wait for UPDATE to finish before SELECT

Tags: sql, symfony, select, doctrine-orm, sql-update

After a few debug, I'm facing an issue I can't find an answer.
Basically, I'm doing an UPDATE statement, then a SELECT statement on the same table.
It seems that when the SELECT happen, the UPDATE is not finished because I get the old values.

Why is the update not finished, and how to make it wait before the select ?

Here are the two statements

UPDATE

```
$stmt = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getConnection()
             ->prepare('UPDATE Event
                        SET `begin` = :startTo,  `end` = :endTo
                        WHERE ' . $field .' = :' . $field);
$stmt->bindValue('startTo', $startTo);
$stmt->bindValue('endTo', $endTo);
$stmt->bindValue($field, $elem);
$stmt->execute();
$em->flush();
```

SELECT

```
$qb = $em->getRepository('EntOrganizationBundle:Event')->createQueryBuilder('e');
$qb->where('(e.begin BETWEEN :start AND :end
            OR e.end BETWEEN :start AND :end
            OR e.begin <= :start AND e.end >= :end)')
   ->andWhere('e.template = 0')
   ->andWhere('e.break = 1')
   ->setparameter(':start', $start)
   ->setparameter(':end', $end);
$events = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Is that because I use both the query builder and raw SQL ?

Thanks,

Comment: what exactly the question is?

Comment: I just updated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [adhocgeek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/232172/adhocgeek) I solved my problem.
That was a cache issue.

Using both raw SQL and the QueryBuilder does not seems to be a great idea, due to the cache, the QueryBuilder one was not aware of the changes made by the raw SQL one.

I just did a `$em->clear();` before the QueryBuilder one.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html) :

> Doctrine 2 already takes care of proper transaction demarcation for you: All the write operations (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) are queued until EntityManager#flush() is invoked which wraps all of these changes in a single transaction

So, before you submit the query, you need to `flush` or `commit` the update.

Comment: Indeed, I'm doing $em->flush() right after $stmt->execute(). When you say 'submit the query', does it refers to the execute() ? I tried to flush just before, but nothing change.

Comment: By query, I mean the SELECT statement. The symptom you describe is usually indicative of a transaction remaining uncommitted. What code do you have between the UPDATE and the SELECT blocks?

Comment: There is ... nothing between the two queries. The UPDATE block then a call to a function containing the SELECT block.

Comment: You've just said that you call $em->flush() after the update statement, so there's at least that code - what else is there? Are you using the same entity manager in both functions?

Comment: Yes, just that line, I edited to add it to the code. There is nothing more. I am using two instance of the entity manager, declared as `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();`, one for each function.

Comment: That could be the problem - your first em is flushed, but the second knows nothing of this. QueryBuilder uses a DQL cache which means that it might not go to the database to retrieve data if it doesn't know it needs to. I'm not sure if it's possible, but you could try setting QueryBuilder::STATE_DIRTY?

Comment: As an aside, the whole point of using an entity manager is that you have only one. You shouldn't have a situation where you've instantiated many of them.

Comment: I believe so, but without looking at your codebase I can't be certain.

Comment: I used the same entity manager, nothing changed. Might be useless now, but how can I change the state to dirty ?